# There is some confusion about the visual studio debug terget options

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

[image: Visual Studio Debug Target]

I see three options in my Visual Studio Debug Target; I know what IIS and WSL are, but there is an option that matches the name of my solution that I don't know about; what is it?

When I run with that option, the output like this

[image: Output Screen]

Comment: Hi, if you select the option with your solution name and it hosted with Kestrel, please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-7.0. For the second issue that you met, you can try to capture and check the http status of that request, then share the detailed information, thanks.

Comment: Hello, sorry to trouble you and just want to confirm that this issue was solved or not. If not, please help to share more detailed information, that will help us to analysis this issue. If you have already solved it, we are welcome to share the solution in here, that will help other community member who meet the same or similar issues in the future, thanks.

Comment: I apologies for the delay in responding; this issue has not yet been resolved.  i am  running  my project on IIS . Request status reads as failed